# A difficulty in understanding that $A$ can be regarded as a unitary $End(A)$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

My professor said: "If $A$ is an abelian group and End(A) is a ring under addition and composition of group homomorphisms, then  $A$ can be regarded as an $End(A)$-module under the multiplication defined by:
$$ f(a) = fa, \forall f \in End(A),\forall a \in A  $$ "

Because A is an additive abelian group, the only conditions remaining to prove that A is an  $End(A)$-module, is $$ End(A) \times A \rightarrow A \\ (f,a) \rightarrow fa$$

And

1. $f(a+b) = fa + fb$
2. $(f + g)a = fa + ga$
3. $f(ga)=(fg)a$
4. $I_{End(A)} a = a$

$\forall f,g \in End(A), \forall a \in A$

I am not sure if the above remaining conditions are written in a right form or not , I am confused between when to apply composition of functions and when to apply the  given multiplication in that proof of $A$ can be regarded as a unitary $End(A)$-module(I have already proved that $(End(A), + , \circ)$ is a ring).could anyone please check the above conditions for me?

Also, I do not know if the above conditions are written in a correct way, how can I prove them, could anyone help me please?

Thanks!!

Comment: All of the properties follow instantly from the definion of the module action. Which one are you having trouble with? Seems like you're overthinking things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one mistake (apparently): the first one should be $f(a+b)=fa+fb$

> I am not sure if the above remaining conditions are written in a right form or not

Modulo the typo above, they are in the right form. You could write the module action using $\cdot$ if it helps you keep things straight. E.g.:
1. $f\cdot (a+b) = f\cdot a + f\cdot b$

1. $(f + g)\cdot a = f\cdot a + g\cdot a$
2. $f\cdot (g\cdot a)=(f\circ g)\cdot a$
3. $I_{End(A)}\cdot  a = a$

> I am confused between when to apply composition of functions and when to apply the given multiplication

Composition of functions only arises in the condition testing $(f\circ g)\cdot a=f\cdot(g\cdot a)$, which is the first place where two functions appear composed. For example, the left hand side is, by definition $(f\circ g)(a)=f(g(a))$, and the right side is $f\cdot(g(a))=f(g(a))$. Obviously these are identical.

Comment: I do not understand why can not we write $f . (g.a) = (f.g).a$?

Comment: And in my opinion $(f \circ g)(a) = f(g(a))=f(ga) = fga$  and $f.(g(a)) = f.(ga) = fga $..... am I right?

Comment: @Intuition If you are using $\cdot$ for the new module action, then $f\cdot g$ is a meaningless expression.

Comment: In the second comment, yes you are right, except that you seem to be indicating the module action with both $\cdot$ and juxtaposition which is kind of inconsistent.

Comment: meaningless because our action is from$ R\times A$ to A?

Comment: @Intuition Yes, $R\times A\to A$.

Comment: The proof of (1) is $l.h.s = f.(a + b) = f(a) + f(b) = fa + fb = r.h.s$ and the proof of the second (1) is l.h.s = (f+g).a = (f+g)(a) =(f(a) + g(a)) = (fa + ga) = r.h.s and the proof of (3) is l.h.s = $I_{End(A)}.a = I_{End(A)}(a) = I_{End(A)}a = r.h.s $ ....... am I right?

Comment: @Intuition you are still using both $\cdot$ and juxtaposition in an inconsistent way that makes me think you don't understand.

Comment: what do you mean by "juxtaposition"? you mean my proofs are wrong?

Comment: If my proofs are wrong could u please write the correct one for me?

Comment: Could you tell us the mistake in the proof of the ring actions .... as it is not clear for me also. @rschwieb

Comment: @Intuition For example, $I\cdot a:=I(a)=a$ by definition of $I$.  $f\cdot(a+b):=f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ by definition of an endomorphism, and $f(a)+f(b)=f\cdot a +f\cdot b$ by definition of the module action. Earlier with composition: $(f\circ g)\cdot a:=(f\circ g)(a)=f(g(a))=f(g\cdot a)=f\cdot (g\cdot a)$.

Comment: @Intuition Juxtaposition means writing an operation without a symbol, like $xy$ for the product of $xy$. By jumbling that with $\cdot$ you seemed to be showing me that you didn't fully understand where you were going through these verifications.

Comment: @rschwieb is the answer of question 2 in the given link  the same as the answer of the above question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524379/what-is-the-difference-between-the-answers-of-this-2-questions